# My iPod touch 2nd generation turns on and charges only when my laptop is on sleep mode

Tags: ipod-touch

I have 2nd generation, 8 GB iPod touch. It only turns on and charges when my Lenovo T520 is on sleep mode, as soon as I disconnect it from the laptop or I switch the laptop back on, the iPod switches off.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to ask different? What happens if you try charging it via a wall socket? Or connect it to another computer/laptop? Are you able to use it once it has sufficient charge?

Comment: It doesn't charge or switch on when I connect it to a wall socket or another pc. I can use it while it's connected to the laptop that way but the battery doesn't get fully charged.